# Getting fragment's id into detail controller

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I'm working on a sap fiori Master-Detail application on sap web ide.

i want to filter a table i have on detail view based on an ID i will get from a list in master view.The table's detail view is located in a fragment. I created a js function to filter that table in the detail controller but i can't seem to have the id of the table in the fragment.
Here's my detail-controller's code:

```
this._oView = this.getView();

this._oView.attachAfterRendering(function() {

       var sPath1 = "Qmnum";
       var sOperator1 = "EQ";
       var sValue1 = "10000000";
       var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter(sPath1, sOperator1, sValue1);

       var oBinding = this.byId("tableid").getBinding("items");

        oBinding.filter(oFilter1);
          });
```

i tried using also this

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId();
```

&

```
this.getView().byId();
```

but still undefined.

Comment: have you given viewId in manifest. check it once because when you try to get control using sap.ui.getCore().byId("LOGIN_PG--loginId") . Here LOGIN_PG is id defined in manifest file and loginId is id given to control.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Suryabhan, in which part should i define id in manifest.json ?

Comment: no i am not asking you to define id. if you are not able to access table in dialog that means your id is not correct. check by inspecting what id your table have on browser.

Answer (score 0):

> If XML fragments are used within XML views, giving the view ID as
>   fragment ID will allow calling this.byId(…) in the view’s controller
>   to retrieve controls inside the fragment.

```
var oFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "my.useful.VerySimpleUiPart" );
```

Comment: I want to get the id of the table created in my fragment so that i can use it in my detail controller, but this fragment doesn't have an id

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the fragment and attach it to the current view:

```
// Init fragment
var oFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("herePutJourneyToFragment.fragmentName", this.getView().getController());        

// Attach the fragment to the current view              
this.oView.addDependent(oFragment);
```

After that you should be able to find the table in you view:

```
var oTable = this.byId("tableid");
```

EDITED 13:45 150317 bellow:

[Tutorial](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/4da72985139b4b83b5f1c1e0c0d2ed5a.html).